# Why do planets in our solar system have different chemical compositions?

Tags: solar-system, planetary-formation

Was this caused by turbulence in the disc that went on to form the solar system or was the disc itself just endowed with an uneven distribution of elements?

Comment: What different chemical composition are you talking about, can you give a reference? It's important to know whether you refer to the refractory or volatile elements, bulk or atmosphere, etc.

Comment: From Wikipedia
The elemental composition of Mars is different from Earth's in several significant ways. First, Martian meteorite analysis suggests that the planet's mantle is about twice as rich in iron as the Earth's mantle.[6][7] The planet's distinctive red color is due to iron oxides on its surface. Second, its core is richer in sulphur.[8] Third, the Martian mantle is richer in potassium and phosphorus than Earth's and fourth, the Martian crust contains a higher percentage of volatile elements such as sulphur and chlorine than the Earth's crust does.

Comment: Few things to note here. The difference in iron content might be explained by weaker differentiation (i.e. a geological process) due to the weaker gravity. The other statements are more difficult to interpret, "is richer" doesn't say whether it's 10x or only 1% richer, and then we don't have global samples of mars, just about ~10 tiny Martian meteorites. As for the physics of the PP-disc, it is thought that ice lines played a role in controlling the local reservoir of available minerals and ices in the disc. So just the existence of turbulence locally, doesn't mean uniform global mixing.

Comment: @planetmaker Yes the link gives a good answer to my question

Comment: Why wouldn't they?